# Typeform integrate google map place suggestion api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete, typeform

i want to add google map places suggestion API on typeform specific search text field.
is there possible anyway? because i can not find any way like via JavaScript to embed JavaScript code on typeform or 2nd i try where used this form it's also prevent to return iframe content.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to use a [google places autocomplete field](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) directly inside a typeform.

Is that right?

At the moment this is not possible on Typeform platform.

One workaround could be an intermediary step before the typeform, like a static HTML page where you present the user with such a field, and pass this data as [hidden field](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029114712-How-to-use-Hidden-Fields) to the Typeform.

If you want to restrict people within a certain location to answer your typeform here are some other alternatives:

- using google tag manager ask for user's location, and redirect them out of the typeform if it does not fit your requirements
- intermediary step to ask for user location (via the browser) and redirect them to the typeform or not
- implement Typeform logic on a zipcode or country field.

Hope it helps,
You can also contact Typeform support directly if you have more precise questions.